# How to check data API property when using NuxtJS middleware?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs

I am building a blog-style app where a user can edit and delete his own posts. When he "deletes" his post, a property in the post object is changed from `published: true` to `published: false` . I am not actually removing the post from the database. Now, I sitll want to allow this post to be viewable by the owner of the post if he navigates directly to the post by typing in URL (he may have it bookmarked, too), but I DO NOT want it to be viewable by anyone else, obviously.

I thought maybe page middleware is what I need to use here, but I am unsure how to approach it. Do I somehow check the boolean value of the post's `published` property in the middleware? If so, how? I know how I can check the user state via something like context.store.state.user.uid , but how would I write the logic to check for the `published` property? Do I need to do a firestore query?

Here's an example of a blog post's URL schema (contains post id):

`mysite.com/users/XmdmZMZkzkRdpZ4oLX5u6MYA9B62/posts/hello-world-title-here`

*Note: IF there's a better way to approach this rather than using Middleware (maybe I am overthinking this goal) , let me know! Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to fetch the post somewhere in order to know the `published` boolean.

A middleware is a good idea if you want to redirects the user going to a post he doesn't have access to (or show the error page).

That requires that you fetch the post from here, and that you have access to the current user from the request.

```js
const validatorMiddleware = async ({ req, error, store }) => {
  const post = await axios.get('mypost')
  const user = req.user // can come from a previous middleware

  if (post.author.id !== user.id) {
    error() // Show error page
  }

  store.commit('addPost', post)
}

export default validatorMiddleware
```

This is a possibility, then it depends on how you fetch your data etc.